# How to get transcluded element's scope to be the same as/inherit from isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `navbar` directive and `collapseIcon` directive. I'm am using angularJS 1.2.1. The `collapseIcon` directive is a child element inside `navbar.`

```
<navbar>
    <collapse-icon></collapse-icon>
</navbar>
```

The `navbar` directive has an isolate scope with a `toggle()` function and I want `collapseIcon's` scope to prototypically(?) inherit from the isolate scope. To do this, I read to use the 'transclude' function (I call it linker below) in the `prelink()` function.

I did a lot of `console.log()` statements and I see initially `collapseIcon`'s scope is the same as `navbar`'s but it changes back for some reason.

Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67cgam3h/1/

Here is the code:

```
app.directive('navbar', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        require:"navbar",
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        },
        template: '<div class="navbar" ng-transclude></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            this.expanded = false;
            var that = this;
            $scope.toggle = function () {
                if (that.expanded) {
                    $scope.contract();
                } else {
                    $scope.expand();
                }                
            }
        },
        link : {
            pre: function (scope, element, attrs, navbarCtrl, linker) {
                scope.expand = function () {
                    var height = element.prop('scrollHeight');
                    element.css('height', height + "px");
                    navbarCtrl.expanded = true;
                }
                scope.contract = function () {
                    element.css('height', '42px'); // hard-coded default height
                    navbarCtrl.expanded = false;
                }
                console.log('navbar scope');
                console.log(scope);
                console.log('navbar linking');
                linker(scope, function(clone) { // set the transcluded element's scope
                    console.log('appending navbar elements');
                    element.append(clone);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('collapseIcon', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log("collapseIconScope:");
            console.log($scope);
            $scope.test = function () {
                console.log($scope);
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        },
        template: '\
<div class="collapse-icon" ng-click="test()">\
<span class="icon-line"></span>\
<span class="icon-line"></span>\
<span class="icon-line"></span>\
</div>'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing 2 different scopes because you are transcluding twice: once with `ng-transclude` in the template, and the other - with the transclude function named `linker`.

A transcluded scope with `ng-transclude` protypically inherits from the directive's parent (i.e. the outer scope), whereas your transclude function used the directive's scope as the transclusion scope.

Based on your requirements, you would need to manually create a child scope that inherits from the directive's isolate scope:

```
// navBar directive's function
pre: function (scope, element, attrs, navbarCtrl, transclude) {
   var childScope = scope.$new(false);
   // ...

   transclude(childScope, function(clone){
      element.append(clone);
   })
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that by default, ng-transclude creates a scope that is a sibling of the directive scope (a child of the directive scope's parent).  [This issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5489) is still open, so changing this has been discussed but I don't think it's made it to the stable release yet.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger, I checked the code of the master branch, albeit briefly, so I may have been mistaken. I'll take a look again.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger, ah, I see - I was talking about the child-parent relationship where the directive is the `$parent`, whereas the question is really about prototypical inheritance - where, correctly, transclusion with default scope (as is the case with `ng-transclude`) inherits from the directive's parent. Fixed the answer, thanks!